# Authentication expiry with OpenIDConnect with AAD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure-active-directory, owin, openid-connect

I am authentication my users with OpenIDConnect Owin, Azure AD microsoft login.

I would like to know how long Request.IsAuthenticated with Owin Middleware will return true after a user has logged in with Microsoft.

Is this linked to the expiration time of the ID-token? If so, can I change the expiration time somehow?

Answer (score 1):

`Request.IsAuthenticated` is to valid no matter what type of authentication is being used (Windows, Passport, Forms or our own custom scheme) and not linked to id token.It will be true after successful login

To change the expiry time of the authentication,

Azure AD gives us a [refresh token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token#refresh-an-access-token) to use when our **access token**(not id token) is about to expire i.e., that when we ask AAD for a new token and provide this refresh token, AAD will give us a new token without asking the user to re-authenticate.

Also,Technically there is no specified way to "refresh" an ID Token using a refresh token. Therefore, the only way to get a new ID Token is to re-authorize/authenticate the user by redirecting the user to the authorization endpoint